# List within List in Xamarin.forms xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a ditcionary with values as lists of string. In my xaml I bind the dictionary to a list and within that list I print out the key. I then want to print out a list of value for each key. What should I bind to the Value list and what should I bind to the Value label?

Here is my xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name ="QuoteListView" ItemsSource ="{Binding dict}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate >
        <ViewCell >
          <ViewCell.View >
            <StackLayout>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                <Label Text ="{Binding Key}" FontSize="10" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" />
              </StackLayout>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
                <ListView x:Name ="QuoteTextListView" ItemsSource ="{Binding }" HasUnevenRows="True">
                <Label Text ="{Binding }" FontSize="10" TextColor="White"/>
                </ListView>
              </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

This is what I want to achieve:

Name 1

"Quote 1 text"

"Quote 2 text"

Name 2

"Quote 1 text"

"Quote 2 text"

...

Comment: can you post a pictorial representation of thing that u want to achieve ?

Comment: @saketkumar Post updated!

Comment: follow below link ,this will give u what u want if not let me know
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/44350/how-to-create-an-accordion-in-xamarin-forms-listview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `ListView` Grouping. You can turn your dictionary into 2 lists. `ListView` Grouping info can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Grouping).

Basically you will create an object to store the list of Quote strings. Then you take that object and put it into another object representing the list of Names. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: can you elaborate with example please. i have same issue. i have list which itemsource class have another list inside it.how can i bind that in my list.??

Comment: @NeelamPrajapati Check out [link](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2018/02/25/listview-bindings-on-xamarin-forms-and-observable-groups/)